# using the add function in a modular project

Tags: module, alloy

I have modeled my project in alloy, and I want to separate the run part from the modeled part of my project.
In some fact and predicate I use the add function in cardinality comparison.
Here is an example :

```
#relation1 = add[ #(relation2), 1]
```

When the run part and the model part are in the same file all work successfully.

But when I separate them in 2 files, I have the following syntax error :

```
The name "add" cannot be found.
```

I thought it needed to open the integer module where there is an add function, so I have opened it it the header of the model part.
But then the runtime ask me to specify the scope of this/Univ.

```
You must specify a scope for sig "this/Univ"
```

Here is an example : 
first the model in one module

```
module solo

open util/ordering [A] as chain
//open util/integer

sig A{ b : set B}

fact {  all a : A - chain/last | #(a.next.b) = add[ #(a.b), 2]}

sig B{}
```

then the run part in another module :

```
module due

open solo

run {#(solo/chain/first.b) = 2 }for 10 B, 5 A
```

when I call it like this I have the "the name add cannot be found" error.
When I uncomment the integer module opening, I have the "You must specify a scope for sig "this/Univ"" error.

What should I do that to make it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken + is the union operator and thus can't be used to perform additions.

Which version of alloy are you using ?

I think the add[Int,Int] function was added recently, before it used to be plus[int,int].

You might want to try plus[Int,Int] and see if it solves your problem.
Else it would be nice to have access to your models. Maybe the error comes from elsewhere.

Comment: I use alloy 4.2. You are right the + is the union operator. I am mistaken. I tried the plus operator and when the command and the model are in the same file it works, as with the add operator. But when I try with the command in a separated file, it seems that the file opened with the keyword open does not have access neither to the add, neither to the plus operators.

Comment: I think it would be easier to diagnose what is wrong if you share the problematic models.

I have actually difficulties what you mean by separating the run part from the model part.

Comment: Explicitly opening util/integer should work. The missing scope for "Univ" is a strange error and I would also like to see the model that causes it.

Comment: I have modified my question to present a model with that error.